# Why isn't my custom error handling working?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I've got a custom error handler implemented in code like this:

```
Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    'get the exception
    Dim ex = Server.GetLastError()

    'log it
    ex.LogToFile()

    'clear the error
    Server.ClearError()

    'build route data to route this exception to ErrorController
    Dim routeData = New RouteData()
    routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error")
    routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index")
    routeData.Values.Add("exception", ex)

    'route to the error controller, preserving the context
    Dim controller As IController = New Controllers.ErrorController()
    controller.Execute(New RequestContext(New HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData))
End Sub
```

Then the `/error/index` action method shows the exception in a user friendly way. On my development machine, this works fine. But on the deployed server, when an exception is thrown, instead of my error message, it tries to use a canned error page, like `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr\<LANGUAGE-TAG>\500.htm`.

If I specify my own 500 page, it uses it, but without my custom handling.

If I remove the 500 page like so:

```
  <httpErrors>
    <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
  </httpErrors>
```

I just get a white screen of death with this message:

```
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

So, how can I get my error handling to do the right thing?

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that the [`HandleErrorAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) is causing this. Check in the Global.asax, and App_Start/FilterConfig.vb to see if a line like `filters.Add(New HandleErrorAttribute())` exists.

If the `HandleErrorAttribute` is used and custom errors are turned on, MVC will keep all unhandled exceptions in the MVC workflow. Meaning any unhandled exceptions from views/controllers/etc won't bubble up to ASP.NET or IIS to allow `Application_Error` to see the exception, and you'll see the view at /Views/Shared/Errors.vbhtml

Looking at your code, you're nearly doing what the `HandleErrorAttribute` does. If you're just trying to return a simple view on failure, the attribute does allow you to set the default view it uses instead of the generic Error view.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that IIS really wants to handle 500 errors unless you explicitly tell it not to with the following line of code:

```
    'force our handling, instead of IIS handling
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = True
```

This article provides a lot of info about this:

http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Apr/29/IIS-7-Error-Pages-taking-over-500-Errors